# C# wpf hittest diagonal line

Tags: c#, wpf

I try a hittest on a diagonal line.

Unfortunatly the hittest returns true, when clicking
on the bounding box of the line.

Know anyone whether it is possible to filter that without
calculate it manually? Thanks!

```
    private void MainWindow_PreviewMouseDown(object sender)
    {
        System.Windows.Point pt = Mouse.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);

        SheetHitResultList.Clear();

        VisualTreeHelper.HitTest((UIElement)sender, new HitTestFilterCallback(OnHitTestFilter), new HitTestResultCallback(MyHitTestResult), new PointHitTestParameters(pt));
        if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            if (SheetHitResultList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (HitTestResult htr in SheetHitResultList)
                {
                    var temp = htr.VisualHit;
                    if (temp.GetType() == typeof(Line))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Hitted");
                        //Here the MessageBox will be shown even when I click on the bounding box
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public HitTestResultBehavior MyHitTestResult(HitTestResult result)
    {
        SheetHitResultList.Add(result);

        return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
    }

    HitTestFilterBehavior OnHitTestFilter(DependencyObject target)
    {
        if (target.GetType() == typeof(Line))
        {

            return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;
        }
        else
        {
            return HitTestFilterBehavior.ContinueSkipSelf;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please make a minimal reproducible example? Your code contains references to undefined objects like `SheetHitResultList` that makes it hard to copy-paste. EDIT: I can't reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an adaptation of some code I have for hit testing:

```
    private void Canvas_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pt = Mouse.GetPosition(ParentCanvas);
        AddIfInPath(ParentCanvas, pt);
    }
    private List<DependencyObject> foundControls = new List<DependencyObject>();
    private void AddIfInPath(Canvas canvas, Point point)
    {
        Point pt = new Point(point.X + 1, point.Y + 1);
        var hitTestArea = new EllipseGeometry(pt, 1, 1);
        foundControls.Clear();
        VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(
              canvas
            , null
            , new HitTestResultCallback(SelectionResult)
            , new GeometryHitTestParameters(hitTestArea));
        if (foundControls.Count > 0 && foundControls[0] is Line)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hit!");
        }
    }
    public HitTestResultBehavior SelectionResult(HitTestResult result)
    {
        IntersectionDetail id = ((GeometryHitTestResult)result).IntersectionDetail;
        switch (id)
        {
            case IntersectionDetail.FullyContains:
            case IntersectionDetail.FullyInside:
            case IntersectionDetail.Intersects:
                foundControls.Add(result.VisualHit);
                return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
            default:
                return HitTestResultBehavior.Stop;
        }
    }
```

My view

```
  <Grid>
    <Canvas PreviewMouseDown="Canvas_PreviewMouseDown"
            Name="ParentCanvas"
            >
        <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="700" Y2="500" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
    </Canvas>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note that hit testing is extremely expensive and hence relatively slow.
If you wanted to use this programmatically to find whether a point is on a given line and do that just once then hit testing would likely be fast enough.
If you want to do numerous hit test checks then they might not be a good way to go.
A Bresenham line algorithm is integer based and would very quickly give you a list of integer X,Y cells between two given points.
Round your double based x,y values and compare.